Get Currently Choosen Iteration from the Iterationpicker of the Sprint -Backlog Board
I am developing an Azure DevOps extension. Currently, I'm trying to get the selected iteration from the iteration picker of the iteration backlog board:

I have already tried to get the iteration ID using the SDK.getConfiguration method, but it isn't returning any iteration data. Does anyone have an idea if there is some kind of event I could use to get the currently selected iteration? To clarify, I am referring to the iteration chosen in the picker, not the iteration that fits within the current timeframe and is marked as "current"/"Aktuell" in the screenshot.
Any help would be much appreciated.

I noticed a public extension Sprint Goal, which is used to set a goal for your sprint. You can refer to the source code for getting the current selected iteration.

